# TypeError: str expected, not NoneType - Docker run problem with .env file in python

Tags: python, windows, docker, operating-system, .env

I have a python RAG script that works fine locally (Windows).

My understanding is that the problem is related to the .env file when it is called in basic_rag.py

```
os.environ['OPENAI_API_KEY'] = os.getenv('OPENAI_API_KEY')
```

When I run it with docker:

```
TypeError: str expected, not NoneType
```

This is the file structure:

```
APP
 chroma
 data
   text.pdf
 .env
 .gitignore
 basic_rag
 Dockerfile
 requirements.txt
 style
```

The Dockerfile code is:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim

WORKDIR /rag-test

COPY ./data  ./data/
COPY ./basic_rag.py ./main.py

COPY ./requirements.txt ./

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["python", "main.py"]
```

I am new to Docker and cannot find a solution for this Error.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `os.environ['OPENAI_API_KEY'] = os.getenv('OPENAI_API_KEY')` What is the purpose of this code?  You're assigning an environment variable to a value that it _already has_.  This is the equivalent of assigning `a = a`.  What is the actual point here?

Comment: How exactly are you running docker?  It won't recognize a `.env` file by default.  You need to use the `--env-file` argument.

Comment: Thank you for asking @John Gordon. The actual point here is that this is the line that the Error is referencing to. That is why I describe the problem as related to the .env file that has the OPENAI_API_KEY.

Comment: Where should I use the --env-file argument? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, and I'm asking you what is the purpose of that line of code, because as far as I can see, it is nonsense.

Comment: `--env-file` is an argument to `docker run`.

Comment: I used `--env-file ./.env`, is it ok? I am getting an AuthenticationError: Error code: 401. The key is valid though. Thanks @JohnGordon

Comment: Complete run code> `docker run -p 8080:8080 --env-file ./.env rag-test`

Answer (score 0):

The line you quote does nothing and you should just delete it.

You're getting a problem when the environment variable isn't already set.  In that case, `os.getenv()` returns `None`.  You're then trying to assign an environment variable the value `None`, but environment variables can only have string values.

Conversely, if the environment variable is already set, then this line takes the current value from the environment, and assigns the same environment variable the same value.

So, the only function of this line is to throw the error you show if the variable isn't set.  You can give a clearer error, if that's the case:

```py
if 'OPENAI_AI_KEY' not in os.environ:
  logging.critical('OPENAI_AI_KEY environment variable is not set')
  sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: The environmental variable is set in .env. When you run the app locally it works perfectly well. The error is generated when running Docker. I deleted the above mentioned line. The error message states the there is an `AthenticationError: Incorrect API key provided:` although it is a totally valid key. I will research more...

Comment: As discussed in the comments in the question, nothing you've shown reads a `.env` file.  Neither the Python code nor the Docker ecosystem will automatically load it into the Unix environment.

Comment: Ok. so is there anything else I need to add besides `docker run -p 8080:8080 --env-file ./.env rag-test`?